# Group Order and Invoices By Stores

Tags: orders, invoice, stores

I have a "Website" and 8 "Stores" attached to this "Website"

Whenever an order is processed through any of the "Store" i want the order to reflect in following way.

1. "Website" should be able to see the orders of all stores in the "Order" history with option to filter order by Stores.
2. "Store" should only see his order.

How does Magento handles this internally ? or any Magento extension support this architecture ? i tried searching and installing the Magento instance to try it by myself, but i am having hard time figuring this out, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are each store has different administrator?

Comment: Yes, each store will have different administrator.

Comment: then set role and permission for the user

Comment: My Question more over is for Administrator of the "Website" or "Main Store" Are they able to view all the orders ? from the different stores ?

Comment: set role as administrator for `Website` administrator, and create another role like `storeadminitrator` and assign the administrator of the stores to this role and set permission for this role

Comment: Administrator of the "Website" can access all stores

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar are you talking about admin users here?

Comment: @DavidManners i am talking about store administrators, for each store we have different store admins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento CE doesn't support ACL based on Website/Stores/StoreViews.

Magento EE supports ACL based on Websites, but afaik not on a deeper level.

There are lots of extensions which tell you, they can do this, just search for "magento Advanced Admin Permission", but be careful with these extensions. This is a deep change in magento and one need a deep understanding to implement this. Not every extension developer has this deep understanding...